# ggplot2 geom_line indicating group size

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_group_order.html

```
h <- ggplot(Oxboys, aes(age, height))
h + geom_line(aes(group = Subject))
```

Produces

[image: a line plot with one line per Subject]

But if two Subjects have exactly the same line, one subject's line will hide the other. Could we use line thickness or intensity to indicate the number of subjects who have the same line? Could we add a bubble using geom_point() to indicate the number of subjects?

Comment: You can add `aes(size=numbersubjects` to a `geom_line` or `geom_point` call.

Comment: @jraab that can't work. There's one line per subject, which is automated by `group`, and thus there's no such thing as `number_of_subjects` per line.

Comment: Can you give some example data, it is unclear from your example what `aes(group=Subject)` signifies. If there are multiple subjects per group, I would aggregate the data by group before plotting and use that in `aes(size)`, but without data it is unclear. If each subject is independent and there is no group associated, then the `alpha` suggestion below would be best.

Comment: Yup, I asked a silly question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use `geom_line(aes(group = 'Subject'), alpha = .5)`. Play around with the alpha values.

Answer (score 3):

You could accomplish it by first mapping the `colour` and `size` aesthetics and then adjusting their values using the `scale_size_manual` and `scale_colour_manual` functions. Below is a demonstration of the approach.

```
# a fake data set with two pairs of identical lines:
df <- data.frame(t = c(1:10, 1:10, 1:10, 1:10), 
                 a = c(1:10, 1:10, seq(5, 8, length =10), seq(5, 8, length =10)), 
                 c = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 10))

ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = a, group = c)) + 
geom_line(aes(size = c, colour = c)) + 
scale_size_manual(values = c(4, 2, 3, 1.5)) + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red", "blue", "yellow"))
```

[image]

You must consider how your grouping factor (in the example `c`) is ordered, because the lines are also plotted in this order. So the line which is plotted first should get a larger value for `size`.

Comment: Thanks! `scale_foo_manual` feels like an awkward hack here. It's not that different subjects deserve different widths / colors, it's that multiple subjects' lines are overplotted.